# Rails: attribute evaluates as nil even though it is defined in db and visible via .inspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here.

I defined a Comment model with several attributes, including commenter_id, link_id and others.  For any initialized comment object, comment.commenter_id always returns nil, even when manual inspection of the sqlite db shows that the appropriate integer is stored in the commenter_id column, and .inspect also reveals that the attribute is appropriately defined.  None of the other attributes have this problem.  I'm stumped.

line in comment.rb:

```
belongs_to :commenter_id, :class_name => "User"
```

line in user.rb:

```
has_many :comments, :foreign_key => "commenter_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `comment.rb`, it should be `belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => "User"`. Rails adds `_id` automatically.

Comment: Sneaky, sneaky rails.  That solved the problem, thanks so much!  I had done this properly in other models but had since forgotten this rule.  So many conventions!